# Problem with Vitis 2022.2 compile versus 2019.1 compiler when using a -D argument to pass a header file in

Tags: gcc, xilinx, microblaze

I am running into an issue when compiling code for the Microblaze where in any mb-gcc compiler (2021.1 or greater) seeing compliable code in 2019.1 mbb-gcc not work.  It fails when trying to resolve a #include TEST_FILE where TEST_FILE is a macro being sent via the -D command in the makefile.  See an example below:

```
C:/Xilinx/Vitis/2022.2/gnu/microblaze/nt/bin/mb-gcc -g -Wall -mlittle-endian -nostartfiles -pedantic -DTEST_FILE=\"test_file.h\" -I{LOCATION of the test file} -MM main.c
```

And then in the main.c I use:

```
#include TEST_FILE
```

In 2019.1 compiler I can compile just fine, but with 2022.2 I end up getting the following error:

```
error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like another layer of shell expansion was added. You need a total of three backslashes in front of each quote to compensate for it:

```
C:/Xilinx/Vitis/2022.2/gnu/microblaze/nt/bin/mb-gcc -g -Wall -mlittle-endian -nostartfiles -pedantic -DTEST_FILE=\\\"test_file.h\\\" -I{LOCATION of the test file} -MM main.c
```

Comment: I tried this but got the same error :(

Comment: Maybe my environment is different. Try different numbers of slashes. Seems like 1 and 3 don't work, so try 2,4,5,6,7,etc. The compiler error is ultimately caused because the quotes are getting removed.